# Which fonts come with OpenOffice / LibreOffice?

Tags: fonts, openoffice, libreoffice

Is there a list of all the fonts which come with OpenOffice / LibreOffice ?

Comment: Yes there is, and it is maintained [on the Document Foundation wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Fonts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Partly* answering my own question:

*LibreOffice* comes with these fonts, as posted [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/3811/how-can-i-get-more-fonts/):
[image]

And here are *some* of the fonts that come with *OpenOffice*, accroding to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice#Fonts):

> OpenOffice includes OpenSymbol, DejaVu,the Liberation fonts (from 2.4 to 3.3) and the Gentium fonts (since 3.2). Versions prior to 2.3 included the Bitstream Vera fonts. After 3.4 the GPL-licensed Liberation fonts were removed and replaced by the Apache-licensed ChromeOS fonts Arimo (sans serif), Tinos (serif) and Cousine (monospace). OpenOffice will also use the default fonts of the running operating system.

Comment: OK, +1. I am surprised they would risk breaking exportability to Office with that many fonts.

Answer (score -2):

Fonts are inherited by from the OS, not the application. If you want to know what fonts you will have in any product, open your fonts folder.

Programs adding fonts is not common, especially for something where the file needs to be shared and still look good.

Photoshop is a good exception, but [OpenOffice plays it safe:](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/General/How_can_I_add_fonts_to_OpenOffice?)

How can I add fonts to OpenOffice?

> OpenOffice.org uses the fonts that are installed in your system. Add
>   new fonts using the Font management tools for your Operating System
>   (for example in Microsoft Windows, you add new fonts via Control Panel
>
> > Fonts). You may need to restart OpenOffice.org (including the Quickstarter), to see the new fonts in the Font Name list box.

And, LibreOffice also seems [to play by the rules:](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/3811/how-can-i-get-more-fonts/)

> The set of fonts is not property of the office suite, but only the
>   configuration of your operating system. Install the necessary fonts in
>   the system and they will be available in office applications.

Comment: A program can install fonts to the system during its installation though, and OpenOffice/LibreOffice may do so.

Comment: @afrazier I added some information for you, it really plays to best practices when you want people to adopt your product.

Comment: @AthomSfere - I think the OP wanted to know the list of LO "bundled fonts", some are mentioned [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/4.0#Core).

Comment: @AthomSfere: Thanks to your link, and contrary to what you have wrote, LibreOffice *does* add new fonts. Please see my own answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to my knowledge and experience, this answer is incorrect.  LibreOffice installs quite a few fonts when it is installed.  See: https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Fonts